# ¿Como se resuelve el error AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'?

Tags: python-3.8

Estoy empezando a programar árboles de decisión pero me sale un error.

Éste es el código:

```
import pandas as pd   
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#graficar el arbol de decision

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz   
import graphviz  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
```

Éste es el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8877e2cc438a> in <module>
      6 
      7 from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
----> 8 import graphviz
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     10 import numpy as np

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\__init__.py in <module>
     25 """
     26 
---> 27 from .dot import Graph, Digraph
     28 from .files import Source
     29 from .lang import escape, nohtml

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\dot.py in <module>
     30 
     31 from . import backend
---> 32 from . import files
     33 from . import lang
     34 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in <module>
     20 
     21 
---> 22 class Base(object):
     23 
     24     _engine = 'dot'

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in Base()
     26     _format = 'pdf'
     27 
---> 28     _encoding = backend.ENCODING
     29 
     30     @property

AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'
```

Comment: Pues el error te dice que tal módulo no tiene una función `ENCODING`. Verifica si esta bien escrita y que el módulo tiene esa función. Sería bueno que leas la documentación

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Dos cosas: 1) Revisa que la versión de graphviz que instalaste sea compatible con la versión de sklearn. 2) Borra la pregunta que pusiste en SO en inglés (o tradúcela a inglés).